# How can i send Mails within my Typo3 extension

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I get results  from a jQuery Survey in JSON within my Typo3 Extension. Now I want to send these results with the Typo3 Mail API to my Inbox. According to the documentations following shoud do the work

```
$mail = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Mail\MailMessage::class);
$mail->from(new \Symfony\Component\Mime\Address('john.doe@example.org', 'John Doe'));
$mail->to(
   new \Symfony\Component\Mime\Address('receiver@example.com', 'Max Mustermann'),
   new \Symfony\Component\Mime\Address('other@example.net')
);
$mail->subject('Your subject');
$mail->text('Here is the message itself');
$mail->html('<p>Here is the message itself</p>');
$mail->attachFromPath('/path/to/my-document.pdf');
$mail->send();
```

so my code looks like this:

```
namespace TYPO3\CMS\Core\Mail;
 
  if (!file_exists( dirname(__DIR__, 2).'/vendor/autoload.php' )) {
    throw new \RuntimeException(
    'Could not find vendor/autoload.php, make sure you ran composer.'
          );
     } else {
        require dirname(__DIR__, 2).'/vendor/autoload.php';
  }


use Symfony\Component\Mime\Address;
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Email;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\MailUtility;


$mail = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Mail\MailMessage::class);
$mail->from(new \Symfony\Component\Mime\Address('john.doe@example.org', 'John Doe'));
$mail->to(
   new \Symfony\Component\Mime\Address('receiver@example.com', 'Max Mustermann'),
   new \Symfony\Component\Mime\Address('other@example.net')
);
$mail->subject('Your subject');
$mail->text('Here is the message itself');
$mail->html('<p>Here is the message itself</p>');
$mail->attachFromPath('/path/to/my-document.pdf');
$mail->send();
```

I just getting errors. Does anyone know how i can achieve this?

Following error i get

```
Notice: Undefined index: TYPO3_CONF_VARS in /var/www/html/local_packages/ext_sitepackage/public/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Mail/Mailer.php on line 170
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is the same question as you already posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71343304/typo3-mail-api-doesnt-send-mails).

This will never work like this. You need to either build a fully fledged TYPO3 extension or a standalone application using [symfony/mailer](https://github.com/symfony/mailer) directly.

Comment: yes it is...
I do have my sitepackage. That is a fully fledged extension right? All SynfonyMail functions are working fine... but the Send() function is not (last line)

Comment: If your code is in the sitepackage, how is it invoked? Why do you use `namespace TYPO3\CMS\Core\Mail;` and not your own namespace? And why do you need that autoload code block? Normally TYPO3 handles that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is missing `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['MAIL']`.

You stumble over the fact that you're programming past the conventions and requirements of TYPO3, but then you're surprised that the framework's functions don't work...

Answer (score 0):

Create a middleware in your sitepackage, and register it correctly. Check for a special route and let the rest run. If handling, use the code there.

You need to run the mailing code in a (full) bootstrapped Typo3 context:

- in a middleware
- extbase plugin registered with pageNum directly

Your pasted code looks weired in a lot of ways. Just putting a file in a extension folder do not mean that is correctly a typo3 extension.

Maybe you want to start and have a proper extension setup first, with the corresponding readings:

- ext_emconf.php / composer.json as a minimum
- code files in 'Classes/' subfolders

then decide with which way you want to handle the "ajax" call and send the email, there are several possibilities (as already mentioned above) .. than read and implement that solution the proper and correct way.

Just having a php file directly referenced/called and just bootstpping the composer autoloader do not and never will be bootstrapping Typo3 with all needed configuration bootstrapping (gathering confings from extensions, Local/AdditionalConfiguration, siteconfig and and and).

And generally a package/extension should have a namespace something like following (as a convention):

<extensionname.....

an thus registered as psr-4 autoloading in your extension composer.json ..

Starting to implement the peaces to simulate a Typo3 bootstpraping in that file is not good and will make a lot of headache ... it's easier to have a proper sitepacke/extension structure.